# Suppose $f(g(t))$ is differentiable. Does this neccesarily imply that $g(t)$ is differentiable?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by $t \rightarrow f(g(t))$  is differentiable.

I've been thinking whether this imply $g(t)$ must be differentiable ?

I know the chain-rule, but here one assume that $g(t)$ is differentiable ?

Comment: No. Let $f$ be a constant function.

Comment: If the example of a constant function seems too easy, let $g(t)=|t|$ and let $f(t)=t^2$ or $t^3$.

Answer (score 1):

Standard example for a function  that is not differentiable (at $0$) is $g(t)=|t|$, now take, for example, $f(t) = -t^2$, and note that $f\circ g$ is differentiable (actually in this case $f\circ g = f$) providing the counter-example.